# How to use NASA Digital Elevation model data?

Tags: c#, gdal, dem, java, geotiff-tiff

I've heard it is possible to use NASA elevation model to determine approximate elevation at (lat;lng) point.
This might be really useful for my upcoming project since Google Elevation API has weird limitations...and I don't really like USGS Elevation Query Web Service because of its speed. I'd want to have elevation query tool/framework on local computer, which works with local file.

I did my homework, and found GeoTiff files might be downloaded with no problem. But I've failed to find any useful documentation or framework.

Can somebody share a link to the specs, or example or tutorial on how to work with GeoTiff files?
Is there any frameworks to get this done (.NET,Java,C++,C - doesn't really matter)?

According to what I see in the GeoTiff files and its header files, I assume each tiff represents small area and pixel color (16 bit value) indicates elevation there in meters. Is that correct?

Comment: I didn't know there's a GIS section. How do I move my question there?

Comment: Interesting question, but voting to close and move to GIS.

Comment: @AlexD Since it's not one of the most common alternate topics, I think a moderator has to do it. I have flagged the question to get the moderators' assessment.

Comment: @erickson Thanks! meanwhile, I've found framework in C#, which pretends it can handle GeoTiffs.

Comment: I am not sure which Tiff's you're talking about and what resolution you need but ASTER GDEM seems to be most detailed DEM for FREE :) Check http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17989/how-to-download-the-entire-aster-gdemv2-dataset. ASTER is 30m. SRTM is 90m.

Comment: @Tomek: Free to a certain degree - there are some restrictions on the usage, so you should check ASTER's license. SRTM, on the other hand, is public domain data, so there are no restrictions.

Comment: @AlexD Hi, is there any progress on that topic?

Answer (score 3):

If you're referring to NASA's [SRTM dataset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuttle_Radar_Topography_Mission), there is an alternative to GeoTIFF file format - you can [download HGT files](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/), which are simpler to decode (see the [Quickstart PDF](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/Quickstart.pdf) and the [rest of the SRTM documentation](http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/Documentation/)).

You can also check out my answer to a similar question: [How to get an elevation profile for a gps track?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/17014/how-to-get-an-elevation-profile-for-a-gps-track/17252#17252)

Answer (score 2):

digging deep enough I've found framework that can handle GeoTiff files . it is 
http://www.gdal.org/
I didnt try to use this whole framework, but it has a lot of source code that explains how to use geo data, geo algorithms and standards.
I was even able to build my simple app which works perfect for me so far. 
That's a win!

This framework answers my original question. I can see how to handle and convert GeoTiff files and implement my own light-weight "engine" that fit my needs.

digging even deeper, check out http://freegis.org/database/?cat=1
there's a lot of frameworks, data sets and geo tools listed there. This website might be a good start point if you're working on any kind of geo (geo dependent) project.